# Why are command substitutions executed first?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I'am working on Bash shell. When I enter commands in the following way

```
cmd1 $(cmd2) $(cmd3)
```

the order of executing the commands is:
`cmd2` -> `cmd3` -> `cmd1`

When I look at the [shell operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Operation.html#Shell-Operation) order of the Bash shell, I cannot fully grasp this situation.

Can you specify exactly how the Bash shell handles "command substitution"?
For example, does tokenization return recursively on every command substitution?

Comment: How do you know the order?

Comment: @choroba We can follow it in many different ways. For example, give the shell the `set -x` command, then you can use the command ```sleep 3 $(sleep 5) $(sleep 7)``` . Thanks to the working time of the `sleep` command, we can follow the commands numbers like 3 5 7. Similarly, with a tool such as `htop`, it is possible to make this tracking order instantly.

Comment: What do you mean by "does tokenization return recursively on every command substitution"? It may be an interesting point: apparently, Bash parses tokens when the expansion is performed; other shells may behave differently. On the other hand, tokenization does not happen on the result of expansions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that command substitution, just as any other shell expansion, is designed to provide a dynamic means of generating command-line parameters for executing a command. So in order to run `cmd1` with the output of `cmd2` and `cmd3` as arguments, these two have to be run first.

The exact order of shell expansions can be found e.g. [in the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html). Command substitution is ranked second after brace expansion, and at the same rank as tilde expansion, parameter (i.e. variable) expansion and arithmetic expansion. Those expansions that have equal rank are evaluated *"in a left-to-right fashion"*, i.e. in the order they appear on the command line.

This would mandate that in case of nested substitutions, e.g.

```
cmd1 $(cmd2 $(cmd3)) $(cmd4)
```

the order would be `cmd3` -> `cmd2` -> `cmd4` -> `cmd1` as the first expansion would be that of `$(cmd2 $(cmd3))` which itself needs expansion of `$(cmd3)`, and then expansion of `$(cmd4)`, before the results are passed to the call of `cmd1`.

Comment: @AdminBee if you answered this for him, wouldn't be be fair to give a point to the question?  (maybe you did) it was zero until i gave it a point.

Comment: @BrianThomas I don't think that there should be an obligation to upvote a question only because a contributor found the time to answer it. There are often enough questions to which I happen to know the answer, but where the question isn't really asked to the point, or is a variation of an already existing question, or where by other means the poster could have found the answer on their own with just a little research. That said, _I did_ upvote this question, but obviously someone else found enough issues with its quality to "offset" that vote - or it was the unavoidable drive-by downvote ...

Comment: yeah good point.  i think i was just meaning in general.  frequently im seeing posts that have hundreds of points on the answer and little votes to questions, so im just raising awareness, as it has been raised to me before by seniors here.